# sudo /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle exec /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/rake .... Fails

Tags: ruby, gitlab, rake, rake-task

I have configured gitlab.rb with LDAP, and after failing to sign in, I wanted to test LDAP with:

```
sudo /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle exec /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/rake gitlab:ldap:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - No file specified as Settingslogic source
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/1_settings.rb:173:in `new'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/1_settings.rb:173:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/1_settings.rb:172:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/1_settings.rb:172:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:check => gitlab:gitlab_shell:check => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am new to Gitlab and rake, I tried to search for the problem, but found myself at a dead end.
I don't know what the problem is and am afraid that when I experiment I will break anything else.
Does anyone recognise this problem, can anyone help me find point towards the problem and hopefully a solution?

Much appreciated.

Install directory:

```
[root@centos7template ~]# ll /var/opt/gitlab
total 8
drwx------ 2 git               root         6 Nov  1 08:45 backups
-rw------- 1 root              root        38 Nov  1 08:47 bootstrapped
drwx------ 2 git               root        24 Nov  3 12:28 gitaly
drwx------ 3 git               root        25 Nov  1 08:45 git-data
drwxr-xr-x 3 git               root        19 Nov  1 08:45 gitlab-ci
drwxr-xr-x 2 git               root        31 Nov  3 10:39 gitlab-monitor
drwxr-xr-x 9 git               root       150 Nov  3 10:39 gitlab-rails
drwx------ 2 git               root        23 Nov  3 10:39 gitlab-shell
drwxr-x--- 2 git               gitlab-www  51 Nov  3 12:29 gitlab-workhorse
drwx------ 3 root              root        68 Nov  3 13:39 logrotate
drwxr-x--- 9 root              gitlab-www 154 Nov  3 12:29 nginx
drwxr-xr-x 3 root              root        31 Nov  1 08:47 node-exporter
drwx------ 2 gitlab-psql       root        25 Nov  3 10:39 postgres-exporter
drwxr-xr-x 3 gitlab-psql       root        77 Nov  3 12:29 postgresql
drwxr-x--- 3 gitlab-prometheus root        38 Nov  3 10:39 prometheus
drwxr-x--- 2 gitlab-redis      git         57 Nov  3 12:29 redis
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root        40 Nov  1 08:45 trusted-certs-directory-hash
```

Installed versions:

```
gitaly  v0.43.0
gitlab-config-template  10.1.0
gitlab-cookbooks    10.1.0
gitlab-ctl  10.1.0
gitlab-ctl-ee   10.1.0
gitlab-elasticsearch-indexer    v0.2.1
gitlab-monitor  v1.9.0
gitlab-pages    v0.6.0
gitlab-rails    v10.1.0-ee
gitlab-scripts  10.1.0
gitlab-selinux  10.1.0
gitlab-shell    v5.9.3
gitlab-workhorse    v3.2.0
```

Comment: You should probably be using the `gitlab-rake` command for this and not a `bundle` installation you found. Gitlab uses that for its `rake`. Give that a try.

Comment: Hello Matt, I have also used "sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check" as git user, sudo user and root user. I get the same error, when I execute your suggestion under root, I get the following: [root@centos7template ~]# gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check
`/var/opt/gitlab` is not writable.
Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler/home/root' as your home directory temporarily.
WARNING: This version of GitLab depends on gitlab-shell 5.9.3, but you're running Unknown. Please update gitlab-shell.
rake aborted!
storage "default" is missing a gitaly_address

Comment: Did Gitlab install correctly? What does `/var/opt/gitlab` look like?

Comment: I don't know, I followed a tutorial for gitlab.com.
I'll put the 'll /var/opt/gitlab' output in the question, too long for comment.

Comment: What version of gitlab are you running?

Comment: Hello engineersmnky, I have edited my question with the installed versions, I used the Omnibus method of installation.

Comment: @engineersmnky The package I used is: gitlab-ce-10.1.0-ce.0.el7.x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created new LDAP configuration in gitlab.rb, reconfigured with gitlab-ctl, tried various authentication method, and with simple_tls it worked.

Thanks for all the effort to post comments with questions! Appreciated.